# Given $|A| \times \aleph_0 = 2^{\aleph_0} \times \aleph_0$ can we automatically deduce that $|A| = 2^{\aleph_0}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Given $|A| \times \aleph_0 = 2^{\aleph_0} \times \aleph_0$ can we automatically deduce that $|A| = 2^{\aleph_0}$? Or do we still have to prove bijection between $2^{\aleph_0}$ and $A$?

Comment: Non-expert opinion.  $2^{\aleph_0}\times \aleph_0=2^{\aleph_0}$. so $|A|=2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Do you know that $\kappa\cdot \lambda = \max(\kappa,\lambda)$ when $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ are infinite cardinals?

Comment: The question looks trivial, however when I proposed the solution @herbsteinberg wrote, I was informed that this can not be "proven" trivially. And that bijection still needs to be shown. I'm wondering if the hypothesis of continuum has anything to do with why I couldn't trivially use this.

Comment: @Nizar The continuum hypothesis is $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$ , so is not needed here.

Comment: Are you assuming the Axiom of Choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
|A|\cdot \aleph_0 &= \max(|A|,\aleph_0)\\
2^{\aleph_0}\cdot \aleph_0 &= \max(2^{\aleph_0}, \aleph_0) = 2^{\aleph_0}
\end{align*}
So if $|A|\cdot \aleph_0 =
2^{\aleph_0}\cdot \aleph_0$, then $\max(|A|,\aleph_0) = 2^{\aleph_0}$, and hence $|A| = 2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Okay now I understand, we were informed a while back that we aren't allowed to use the theorem in the first line. I guess I'm going to have to look at the proof (or prove bijection after all). Thank you very much.

Comment: Please review [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).  It's important that you refrain from answering very poor quality questions.  Take a look at the links provided in my link regarding how askers can "Ask a good question".